# Can HashMap contain custom class for key/value?

Tags: java, hashmap

In HashMap<*K*,*V*>, can *K* or *V* be custom class object instead of wrapper class objects??

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test=new Test();       
        HashMap<String, test> a= new HashMap<String, test>();
    }
}
```

Error occurs: test cannot be resolved to a type.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: What is `test` supposed to be?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `HashMap`, it has everything to do with Generics. Read up on those.

Comment: test isn't a type, its an object instance. Notice your instantiation on the line above. What you've written is like putting an actual string in for the first object instead of type String.

Comment: Need Test class object as value in HashMap. Test class will contain some public String variables.

Comment: And how do you `put` objects in a `HashMap`?

Comment: I change my question: What should be K and V in any Map object?? The above sample was just a way to find this ans. (As i am new to java..concepts are not clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hashmap, yes you can include custom types as Key/Value pair.

but that should not be `object` , it must of clearly a `type` .

means a `class` you can mention which becomes `type` for custom types.

example ,

you can define String type variable as `String s = "abc";`

now 
if we try to write like below

```
HashMap<String, s> a= new HashMap<String, s>();
```

it wont compile as `'s'` is not the type rather than its an object of type `String`,

hence it should become like below

```
HashMap<String, String> a= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

so your code like below

```
Test test=new Test();       
        HashMap<String, test> a= new HashMap<String, test>();
```

should become

```
Test test=new Test();       
        HashMap<String, Test> a= new HashMap<String, Test>();
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is of generic type. Hence we can pass any type of objects as key & values.

But if you want to specify the type of Key & values in HashMap you can specify it by writing class name.

But in your code you have used object test to specify Object type.
So you should write something like this

HashMap map=new HashMap();
map.put("string1",new Test());