# Passing HashMap as parameter into a subclass constructor

Tags: hashmap

I've been struggling with trying to figure out the problem and fixing the error when I tried to pass HashMap into a constructor. My scenario is:

I've a Student class:

```
public class Student {
   String name;
   String major;
   String level;
   
   public Student (String name, String major, String level) {
      this.name = name;
      this.major = major;
      this.level = level;
   }    
}
```

I've another class, called TA_Manager that is a subclass of Student. This TA_Manager class uses HashMap to collect the students (who are TA) from the Student class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TA_Manager extends Student {
   HashMap<String, Student> TA;
   
   public TA_Manager(HashMap<String, Student> TA) {
      this.TA = TA;
   }
}
```

In the main class, I've created three student objects and I put two of the students into the HashMap (they are TAs). Then I create a TA_Manager object and pass the HashMap into the TA_Manager class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Student s1 = new Student("A", "CS", "Junior");
       Student s2 = new Student("B", "IS", "Senior");
       Student s3 = new Student("C", "CE", "Senior");

       HashMap<String, Student> TA = new HashMap<String, Student>();       
       TA.put("TA1", s1);
       TA.put("TA2", s2);

       TA_Manager tamgr = new TA_Manager (TA);
   }
}
```

When I run the main class, it returns error:
TA_Manager.java:6: error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
public TA_Manager(HashMap<String, Student> TA) {
^
required: String,String,String
found:    no arguments

I actually have searched this HashMap problem and I followed the solution given on how to pass the HashMap into the constructor:
[Pass a HashMap as parameter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709454/pass-a-hashmap-as-parameter-in-java)
and also from this link on how to pass a class as hashmap value:
[Can HashMap contain custom class for key/value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859041/can-hashmap-contain-custom-class-for-key-value)

But I still get the error message. I don't know how to fix this error. Can anyone bring some light into this. Really appreciated.

Comment: You need to do one of two things, create a default constructor in student, or call the current constructor. What do you want TA.name to be?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because java is trying to call the no-arg constructor of your Student class, but you only have a three argument public constructor.

The simplest solution is to create an empty public constructor for your student.

```
public Student(){
    //do nothing and leave values as null.
}
```

This is not a very practical solution. The problem is a bit conceptual. Your TA class is a Student, but you don't give it a name major or level.

The next way to manage this would be to call the current constructor with some values.

```
public TA_Manager(HashMap<String, Student> TA) {
  super( null, null, null);
  this.TA = TA;
```

}

Now java knows to use the public constructor instead of the no-arg one. I left the values as null because I don't know what default values you would have. This is practical when there are useful default values that you wouldn't need to include during construction.

Personally, I would expect the TA to be a full student AND have a hashmap.

```
public TA_Manager (String name, String major, String level) {
  super(name, major, level);
  this.TA = new HashMap<>();
}
```

In this case you would create the manager, then add all of the students afterwards. It has the advantage that your TA_Manager is a fully formed student though.

Comment: thank you so much for pinpointing my mistakes and providing suggestions.I took your suggestion by adding (calling) a super constructor in the TA_Manager class. Now my program works with no error.

Comment: @ss2 can you 'accept' this answer then? There should be a check near the up/down vote buttons.